# NoSuchFieldError MongoDB Error Spigot (Minecraft Server

Tags: java, mongodb, spigot

This is the error im getting in the console
https://prnt.sc/UEwAWFplmUWn
Here is the line its refencing on console to the mongostorage class and the onEnable that is also referenced.
onEnable: https://prnt.sc/8dnYz-VG7fL8 (the string that is not visible is "database.password")
mongostorage: https://prnt.sc/xO2DnWPeV1wJ
And here is my coreConfig file: https://prnt.sc/o900NtzQt3YJ

(Im sorry if i referenced anything wrong i just started coding and this plugin is not mine i found it on github and idk how to get it to work)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25442) mention, it seems there is multiple mongoDB version on same build path.

I suggest you to relocate your own implementation.

Also, prefer copy paste and use code block instead of showing picture of code or console logs.

Comment: I did some things and now i get this error: https://prnt.sc/VWyJLoCrkbnA
Here is what i changed in the MongoStorage class: https://prnt.sc/UffeiE7_DlHM
(The rest of the connection string is my uri)

Comment: The error seems to be caused by the same things, are you using Maven or gradle ?

Comment: The original project used gradle but i do not know how to use gradle so i switched to maven

Comment: Here is the original github repo: https://github.com/Paroxial/pCore